# Retina Images in HTML Email Signature Outlook 2016

Tags: html, outlook, vml

I am trying to add company logo to signature in outlook but users on iPhone the logo is a blurry. I found an article where it ask to use 2x image as resolution but that did not work as outlook resized image before sending.

The logo in files folder is 268 x 56px but when sent to user 134 x 28px, i found when inspected in chrome developer tools.

https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-retina-images-in-html-email

Here is html code for image.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 6.5.7036.0">
<link rel=File-List href="Standard Signature_files/filelist.xml">
<TITLE>Preview</TITLE>
<!--[if !mso]>
<style>
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->

</HEAD>
<BODY>
        <!--[if gte vml 1]>
            <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600"
             o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f"
             stroked="f">
             <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
             <v:formulas>
              <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
              <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
              <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
              <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
              <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
              <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
              <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
              <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
              <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
              <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
              <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
              <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
             </v:formulas>
             <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
             <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
            </v:shapetype>

            <v:shape id="_x0000_i1029" type="#_x0000_t75" style='width:134px; height:28px; max-width:134px;'><v:imagedata src="Standard Signature_files/logo.png" o:title="logo" /></v:shape>
        <![endif]-->

        <![if !vml]><img src='Standard Signature_files/logo.png' style='width:134px; height:28px; max-width:134px;' v:shapes='_x0000_i1029'><![endif]>      

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: In some of the email clients I look at this in, you made a simple gray rectangle. Just not in Outlook.

Comment: What email client are you referring?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can see it in Litmus. I just think this idea is not going to work. One way you can get retina images to work in Outlook is to hard-code in the image `width="600"`, otherwise Outlook will expand to the width of the image, which nor optimal

Comment: It will not work in litmus, you will need to add this to outlook signature (html file), when you send email from outlook it process this with cid image added as attachment.

Comment: Outlook uses v:shape width and height and resize the image, is there a way to override differently i.e. v:imagedata or using something different in vml.

Comment: If you want an example of how to display retina images in Outlook, when building html emails, see my answer below. If you know of a vml solution, which is not really supported by any email client other than Outlook, please do the research and post your results.

Comment: The only issue is see with hosted version of image, that images are not downloaded automatically (Outlook, Mozilla Thunderbird) so that is reason i choose to go with vml version. Outlook process vml and insert image tag src to cid:image001.png. This option is supported by most of email clients.

Answer (score 1):

This works in every version of Outlook. It takes a 1200px image and condenses it down to 600px. The key for Outlook is to add `<img width="600" />` or it will display the image at the full width. You can use the inline style sheet to direct modern email clients to do other tasks. Outlook will ignore `style="width: 600px; max-width: 600px;"`.

```
<img width="600" alt="name" class="em_full_img" border="0" src="http://example.com/sampleimage.jpg" style="display: block; width: 600px; max-width: 600px; border: 0 !important; outline: none !important;" />
```

The class name just directs a @media query below a cerain width to expand to 100%.

Good luck.

Comment: This works for hosted image but I am trying to use embedded image using cid